# dnf doesn't show all updates compared to yum

Tags: linux, yum, oracle-linux, dnf

I had a CentOS 7 machine which I converted to use OEL 7 some time back using the centos2ol.sh script.

Today, I gave the command: "dnf upgrade" and it showed be that 17 packages were to be upgraded with 220MB to download.

I then selected 'N' to abort and gave the command: "yum update". This shows me that 2 packages will be installed and 46 updated with a 542MB download.

Why this difference?

Comment: That depends on exactly what the differences are... But generally although they can use the same repo's  `dnf` handles dependency resolution differently,  with `dnf` `update` and `upgrade` are the same, while with  `yum`  they are slightly different.

Comment: dnf did not say to update packages such as zlib, teamviewer, minizip, ntfs-3g, xorg-x11-server-common, etc

Comment: Try to regenerate yum cache `yum makecache` and try then.

Comment: I had given the ````yum makecache```` command before giving the commands in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

On RHEL 7 based distris use yum as this is the original package manager for version 7 Releases.
On RHEL 8 based distris you can use dnf.